# Quitar espacios en blanco en opciones de ComboBox

Tags: c#

Estaría interesado en saber como elminar los espacios en blanco en las opciones de comboBox

```
var dtRaiz = new DataTable();
dtRaiz = objPlantilla.ObtenerListadoRaiz(1);
idRaiz.DataSource = dtRaiz;
idRaiz.ValueMember = "idRaiz";
idRaiz.DisplayMember = "Nombre".ToString().Trim();
```

Comment: Veo que seguis teniendo problemas y no entendiste todosssss los comentarios que te dejamos... No, esto: "Nombre".ToString().Trim(); no hace que los nombres salgan sin espacios, porque esto no tiene nada que ver con los datos!!!! esto es el nombre que usa el control para mostrar los miembros, no los datos!!! los datos estan dentro de tu datatable (que es un metodo muy obsoleto a esta altura) y los datos que tenes que arreglar son los que estan ahi adentro...

Comment: ¿Cómo saco entonces los datos de la bbdd sin espacios?

Comment: desconozco como estas trayendo tus datos como para decirte como hacerlo.. eso no esta en tu pregunta... pero en general las bases de datos tambien tienen funciones trim...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que he hecho en los procedimientos de sql, directamente he hecho un LTRIM(RTRIM(Campo)) y listos